# Разобрать строчку

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строчки

```
  Пых Пых1 Пых2 
  Пых   Пых1   Пых2 Пых 
Пых Пых1 Пых2
```

На выходе необходимо получить
['Пых', 'Пых1', 'Пых2']
либо
['Пых', 'Пых1', 'Пых2', 'Пых']

То есть чтобы не было пробелов, создать массив из слов ориентируясь по пробелам. Количество пробелов может быть разное, между словами. Что в начале, что в конце, что между словами.

Comment: [Trim](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.trim.php) + [Explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: explode не выход. С 10 пробелами подряд, на выходе будет 10 пустых значений массива

Comment: Тогда обратите внимание на trim, он не для красоты тут ;) если хочется прям совсем красиво - replace..

Comment: `$str = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$str)` и пробелы не проблема)

Comment: trim удаляет пробелы в начале и конце строчке, но не между словами. То есть между словами может быть 1 и более пробел, explode поделит на 3 если между словами будет 3 пробела.

Comment: Блин, а просто через регулярку можно? Чтобы не применять не trim, ни explode. Сразу получить на выходе массив. Чтобы по 10 операций на переменную не вешать.

Comment: Можно и через регулярку но она тут избыточна [preg_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Однажды писал токенизаторы, вот пригодилась whitespace

```
function tokenize(string $text):array
{
    $substrings = preg_split('/[\pZ\pC]+/u', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    if ($substrings === false) {
        throw new \Exception('preg_split failed on: ' . $text);
    }

    return $substrings;
}
```

Например, `tokenize("  Пых   Пых1   Пых2 Пых ")`
вернет

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "Пых"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "Пых1"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "Пых2"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "Пых"
}
```